# Why scroll/follow menu is bouncing when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why scroll/follow menu is bouncing when scrolling?

(1) My scroll/follow menu **bounces** a lot when scrolling up and down (in mobile devices). How can I fix this to rectify the user experience?

(2) The menu doesn't seems to be on the top of the page too, while scrolling. Can I fix this?

I use it here: http://www.pablitogreco.com/book/#b

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c0pnrvc6/

Html

```
<div class=scroller>Xtango</div>
```

CSS

```
.scroller {
position: relative;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #fff;
z-index: 2}
```

Javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > -1) {
$('.scroller').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());}});
```

Comment: Why can't you just `position:fixed;` it? http://jsfiddle.net/cqqxj6g7/

Comment: I didn't work 100%. Almost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Javascript and make your scroller [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky).

Comment: flawless solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just use css and remove jquery. It is working.

```
.scroller {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 2
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried your suggestion but didn't work100%. Thank you very much though.